# Children are not counted in .hover

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am currently making a website for my HSC (Higher School Certificate) Major Work in Software Design, and I have come across a strange bug. The current version of the website can be seen at http://ymindustries.webfactional.com.
My issue is this: I have jQuery powered dropdown menus. In Chrome, when you hover over the menu button, the menu expands, leaving the menu button causes the menu to retract again. However, moving the mouse down from the menu button to the newly shown menu causes it to retract too, which is an issue since I need users to be able to click on links that will eventually go in the menu. It seems that children do not trigger the hover event. Also, in IE9 the hover event is never triggered at all, even when hovering over the button.

Hopefully this is worded clearly enough.
Thankyou!
YM

Answer (score 1):

It's not a bug. When you move the cursor outside the bounds of the element with `.hover`, you no longer hover it. Simple as that.

Expand the bounds or apply a `.hover` to the menu as well.

Comment: So what am I doing differently to http://www.webdesigndev.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/07/fancydropdown.html? I have been loosely following the tutorial there and theirs has no problems.

Comment: Ah, now I understand what you mean by adding the .hover. I tried that, still no luck :(

Answer (score 1):

Like Tom mentioned you probably want to apply a .hover pseudo class to the sub menu. This shouldn't be too difficult. Looking at your site I think a CSS selector like

`.dropdownMenu:hover { display:inline;
}`

should do the trick.

Comment: Unfortunately, no that did not work. Apparently ID selectors have a higher priority than Class selectors in the Cascade, so I also re-adjusted any conflicting stuff, but to no avail. It still eludes the mouse. Worth noting that while I was using jQuery menus before, I have switched them over to fully CSS and still have the same issue.